# Using DATEPART() in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my dataset called **date** and another one is week_day which is full of NULL values. Using mysql workbench, I want to change each NULL value inside week_day to number of the weekday **date** corresponds. I used the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM dataset;

UPDATE dataset
SET week_day = DATEPART(weekday, date)
WHERE week_day = NULL;
```

However, it keeps giving me an error "Error Code: 1046. No database selected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibility

```
USE your_database;
SELECT *
FROM dataset;

UPDATE dataset
SET week_day = DATEPART(weekday, date)
WHERE week_day = NULL;
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM your_database.dataset;

UPDATE your_database.dataset
SET week_day = DATEPART(weekday, date)
WHERE week_day = NULL;
```

Every object has a relation d table like dataset belongs to a databse/Schema, and as long there is no default schela or you have used USE data_base_schame, mysql doesn't know where your tabke beolngs to

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INT,
>   `date` DATE,
>   week_day  varchar(10)
>   
> );
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `date`,week_day)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2020-07-22',NULL),
>   ('2', '2020-07-28',NULL),
>   ('3', '2020-07-30',NULL),
>   ('4', '2020-07-27',NULL),
>   ('5', '2020-07-28',NULL),
>   ('6', '2020-08-15',NULL),
>   ('7', '2020-07-27',NULL),
>   ('  8', '2020-07-29',NULL),
>   ('9', '2020-07-31',NULL);
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1 SET week_day = DAYNAME(`date`) WHERE week_day IS NULL
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | week_day 
> -: | :--------- | :--------
>  1 | 2020-07-22 | Wednesday
>  2 | 2020-07-28 | Tuesday  
>  3 | 2020-07-30 | Thursday 
>  4 | 2020-07-27 | Monday   
>  5 | 2020-07-28 | Tuesday  
>  6 | 2020-08-15 | Saturday 
>  7 | 2020-07-27 | Monday   
>  8 | 2020-07-29 | Wednesday
>  9 | 2020-07-31 | Friday
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f320163af0876caf6f6f25cb2e84584)*

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know about function "USE". I fixed the code as you suggested + changed the function to WEEKDAY() because I work in mysql and not Microsoft sql server apparently. However, I still have a problem for some reason, command executes without problems, but week_day column stays the same, full of NULL values inside the rows.

Comment: can you provide some data examples please

Comment: "date" column consist of hundreds of rows similar to "2019-04-13''. I want to convert it to weekday.

Comment: i have added an example If you want the number use WEEKDAY instead of DAYNAME

Comment: Amazing! NBK, you are my Hero today. It did solve the problem. Seems like mine "week_day = NULL" is wrong, should be "week_day IS NULL". Also, I didn't know that mysql is case sensitive by default. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for your query is not MySQL.  So the query should use `weekday()` or `extract()` or a similar function:

```
UPDATE dataset
    SET week_day = WEEKDAY(date)
WHERE week_day = NULL;
```

However, the error has to do with your connection, not the specific query so this addresses the second problem not the first.

Note:  Because a function is so handy, there is really no need to store this information in the table.  As you've discovered, it just gets out-of-date.

Comment: I fixed the code as you suggested. However, I still have a problem for some reason, command executes perfectly, but week_day column stays the same, full of NULL values inside the rows. Also, could you elaborate more why I shouldn't store it? I thought to use it later on in future analysis.